# remove horizontal spacing in <ul> with list-style-type:none

Tags: html, css

On http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_ol_list-style-type&preval=none, a nice overview is provided for the different `list-style-type` values.

However, for the value `none`, it still reserves some horizontal space for the empty list symbol. Is there a way to remove this horizontal spacing, so that the text actually moves to the left as if it was no list? I would like to use `text-align:center` on the list items, and this horizontal spacing makes them not really centered. And I need to use `<ul>` because the CMS brings it in that way.

Basically, by default `list-style-type:none` does a `visibility:hidden` on the bullets, while I would like to achieve `display:none` on the bullets instead. What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: use reset.css that is already available in google search

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the browsers default styling that's adding that space, just use a CSS reset to *reset* all of the browsers default styles. Most block elements have some default margin/padding .. even the `<body>` element has 8px of margin applied to it by default.

Here is a link to Eric Meyer's reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Just to see for yourself, add:

```
ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
/* This would be declared in the above reset */
```

Comment: Aha, the padding:0; should be put on the ul/ol. I tried it before on the li but that didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A better way to this these days I found recently is to set the `<ul>` to `display: contents;`. Thus the css should look something like this:

```
ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       display: contents;
   }

ul > li {

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0; 
        text-align: center;
   }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add browser reset styles before you start working with CSS.

You have to add this:

```
ol, li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

for this question.

Answer (score 0):

add

`margin:auto;
float:none;
display block;` to your css for the ol element, this will remove the padding and align the elements in the centre